# Are there any tools available for creating a mock version of a contract in JS/TS?

Tags: smart-contract, wasm, testing, javascript, typescript

Currently, we use "live" versions of our contracts running on a substrate contracts node in our JavaScript tests. This makes them integration tests and difficult to include in simple GitHub actions. It would be ideal if we could somehow run the contract as a mock inside our JS environment. Is it possible to run the contract wasm from within our JS/TS environment as a mock contract? Does anyone have any experience of this?

Comment: "run a contract as a mock" doesn't look like a well defined term to me. Can you please elaborate what you mean? I posted an answer on how you could run some integration tests.

Comment: I mean have a mocked/fake contract in JavaScript without running any code in rust. Essentially having a mirror of the contract but in JavaScript/TypeScript. I realise that the wasm probably can't be repurposed for this but you never know. I see there are contract [tests in polkadot-js](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/tree/master/packages/api-contract/src/test/compare) but I'm not sure how they function.

Comment: You want to rewrite the contract in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do an integration test you would need to spawn a [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) and then use the polkadot.js javscript library in order to interact with it. Another way would be to use the [cargo-contract](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/blob/master/docs/extrinsics.md) command line tool in order to interact with the node. That way you could even script it with some shell script.

Answer (score 0):

We use Github Actions, Cypress, and a contracts-node binary to run E2E tests for Contracts UI. Here is [our CI workflow](https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml), hope it helps.

We use [cypress-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload) to attach the `.contract` file to the tests.

A solution without Cypress is to rename it to `.json` and import it into your tests. Most JavaScript bundlers can be configured to support JSON modules and the `.contract` file is valid JSON

```
import incrementer from './contracts/incrementer.json'; 
const wasm = incrementer.source.wasm;
```